# Making $ax^2+bx+c$ a whole number if and only if $x$ is a whole number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Find all *real* values of $a$, $b$, $c$, so that
$$
f(x) = ax^2+bx+c
$$

is a whole number if, and only if x is a whole number.

---

Here what I've go so far. Since f(0) is an integer, $c$ must be a whole number. Since a whole value of c doesn't change the 'wholeness' of f(x), we can disregard c and assume that

$$
f(x) = ax^2+bx
$$

Since f(1) and f(-1) are whole numbers, $a \pm b$  are whole numbers

Solving system of equations:

$$
a+b=u
$$
$$
a-b=v
$$

(p, q are whole), gives $a=\frac{u+v}{2}$ and $b=\frac{u-v}{2}$, so $a=\frac{p}{2}$ and $b=\frac{q}{2}$, where $p$ and $q$ have same parity (both even, or both odd).

(BTW, odd values of $p$ and $q$ make sence, since if $a=m+\frac{1}{2}$, $b=n+\frac{1}{2}$ then $f(x)=mx^2+nx+\frac{x(x+1)}{2}$ is an integer for any whole x)

Now require
$$
\frac{p}{2}x^2+\frac{q}{2}x=m
$$

to have only whole roots for *any* whole value of m.

This can be rewritten as
$$
px^2+qx-2m=0
$$

Therefore $q^2+8mp$ must be a perfect square for *any* m, otherwise for some $m$-s the roots will be irrational, hence not whole numbers.

Here where I got stuck:
**Prove that if $q$ and $p$ are whole numbers** (of same parity?) **and $p \ne 0$, there exists a whole number $m$, so that $q^2+8mp$ is positive and not a perfect square.**

Looks rather intuitive to me, but I see no way to prove it.

If it is proven, then it immediately follows that $p=0$, therefore $a=0$, consequently $b=\pm1$, since if $|b|>1$ then $\frac{1}{b}$ is fractional, while $f(\frac{1}{b})$ is an integer.

Comment: I don't think your definition of "whole number" is standard. It seems like you might mean "integer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the "only if" part. If $a>0$, then $f(x+1)>f(x)+1$ for large enough $x$. Thus if $f(n)=m$ where $n, m$ are integers, then $f(n+1)>m+1$, so by the intermediate value theorem there exists $x\in(n, n+1)$ such that $f(x) =m+1$. Thus $a$ cannot be positive. A similar argument shows $a$ cannot be negative, so $a=0$. It follows that $b$ is an integer, and this completely characterizes all quadratics with your desired property.

Comment: That was smart!

Answer (score 1):

Take some prime number $r$ that doesn't divide $8p$. Take some quadratic nonresidue $n$ modulo $r$. Then you can always solve the congruence $q^2+8mp\equiv n\bmod r$ for $m$, and that value of $m$ will give you a quadratic nonresidue modulo $r$, a fortiori, a nonsquare.

Comment: Is quadratic nonresidue guaranteed to exist for any prime number $r$?

Comment: Another question: If $a$ is a quadratic nonresidue modulo r and $b ≡ a\;mod\; r$, does that automatically imply that $b$ is also quadratic nonresidue modulo r?

Comment: @cyanide Except for $r=2$, there are always quadratic non-residues mod a prime $r$. In fact, there are $(r-1)/2$ non-residues - this is a consequence of the fact that the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Z/r\mathbb Z$ is cyclic. (You can also trade this fact for knowing that any abelian group of even order has at least one thing that's not a square in it. I'm not sure how one sees it without any group theory though)

Comment: It was a really useful info. I put +1 to this, but the idea by Jason is simpler and therefore better :)